# Gradle dependency on all subprojects

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We have the following project structure

```
projectRoot
|>libs
| |>lib1
| |>lib2
| |>...
|>application
```

where for each `libX` and the `application` we have a gradle subproject.
**whether this makes sense or not shall not be part of this question*

Now the application subproject shall depend on all subprojects in the `libs`-dir.
Therefore the `build.gradle` in `application` contains:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":libs:lib1");
    implementation project(":libs:lib2");
    implementation project(":libs:lib3");
}
```

This means, whenever we add a new library module, we also need to add a new line to that `build.gradle`.

If possible, I would like to avoid this hassle, and have a line like:

```
implementation project(":libs:*");
```

and be good. But it doesn't work like this.

**Is there any way, to make one project automatically depend on all other subprojects e.g. inside a specific directory?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following notation:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':libs').subprojects
}
```

This will define a dependency on all subprojects of the project with the path `:libs`. You may think that you did not define this subproject in your `settings.gradle`, but Gradle subprojects are organized using a tree instead of a flat list, so there must exist a project with the path `:libs` for a project with the path `:libs:lib1` to exist. Check out the [documentation on the `include` method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) for details on this behavior:

```
// include two projects, 'foo' and 'foo:bar'
// directories are inferred by replacing ':' with '/'
include 'foo:bar'
```

Please note, that `subprojects` (which invokes [`getSubprojects`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getSubprojects--)) works recursively. Once you start to add subprojects to your library projects, e.g. a project with the path `:libs:lib1:foo`, they will be used as dependencies of your application project, too.

Comment: Perfect! I also added `include 'libs'` to the `settings.gradle` so I can already put that line in my `application/build.gradle` before a first library is added.